# push tag and branch with same name in git

Tags: git, branch, push, git-push

My situation is as follows I have local repo in which I create tag and branch with exactly same names (project requirement can not change it). Now I have to push branch to origin. On later stage I will have to push tag as well. I suspect to do this I will have to provide full reference path for both but I do not know what are the paths.

Comment: @nwinkler no this is different. This is about local branch and tags.

Comment: In general, it's a really bad idea to have both with the same name, as you can see in the linked answer - it's basically asking for trouble. I would like to understand what kind of requirement would force you to have it like this - what's the reasoning behind this?